# Using mapTree collection and need more colors

Tags: java, user-interface, collections, dictionary, colors

This is for a project in school I have two different questions I would like advice on please. Here are the requirements from the teacher:

"Use Java collections to store pairs of unique colors and their unique hexadecimal values. Store up to 20 of these pairs. Then write a GUI that displays the color and/or hexadecimal values using radio buttons to select a value. When selected the background of the GUI should change to that color."

I read this to mean store them as pairs THEN make a GUI that uses JRadioButtons to change the color of the background.

I have this done and working fine. My issue is that I really feel there should be a more efficient way to make the jrb from the treeMap. I am thinking along the lines of calling the next set to fill the jrb, similar to using an array maybe.

Second part is the colors themselves. I see only a limited amount of colors in netbeans (i.e. no purple!) How can I get these colors included in this project for accuracy?

Not sure but any advise will be very much appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


public final class FinalProject extends JFrame {

private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 700;
private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 800;
private JRadioButton redButton;
private JRadioButton greenButton;
private JRadioButton blueButton;
private JRadioButton aquaButton;
private JRadioButton grayButton;
private JRadioButton fuchsiaButton;
private JRadioButton blackButton;
private JRadioButton limeButton;
private JRadioButton silverButton;
private JRadioButton maroonButton;
private JRadioButton navyButton;
private JRadioButton oliveButton;
private JRadioButton purpleButton;
private JRadioButton tealButton;
private JRadioButton yellowButton;
private JRadioButton cyanButton;
private JRadioButton orangeButton;
private JRadioButton tanButton;
private JRadioButton lavanderButton;
private JRadioButton plumButton;
private ActionListener listener;

public FinalProject()
{ 
TreeMap<String,String> colorselect = new TreeMap<String,String>();
colorselect.put("00FFFF","Aqua");
colorselect.put("008000","green");
colorselect.put("808080","gray");
colorselect.put("ff00ff","fuchaia");
colorselect.put("0000ff","blue");
colorselect.put("000000","black");
colorselect.put("00ff00","lime");
colorselect.put("c0c0c0","silver");
colorselect.put("800000","Maroon");
colorselect.put("000080","olive");
colorselect.put("ff0000","red");
colorselect.put("800080","purple");
colorselect.put("008080","teal");
colorselect.put("ffff00","yellow");
colorselect.put("00ffff","cyan");
colorselect.put("ffa500","orange");
colorselect.put("d2b4bc","tan");
colorselect.put("e6e6fa","lavander");
colorselect.put("dda0dd","plum");

// This listener is shared among all components
class ChoiceListener implements ActionListener
{ 
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{ 
setColor();
}
}

listener = new ChoiceListener();

createControlPanel();

setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
}

public void createControlPanel()
{

JPanel styleGroupPanel = createRadioButtons();

JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

controlPanel.add(styleGroupPanel);

add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

public JPanel createRadioButtons()
{
redButton = new JRadioButton("Red");
redButton.addActionListener(listener);

greenButton = new JRadioButton("Green");
greenButton.addActionListener(listener);

aquaButton = new JRadioButton("aqua");
aquaButton.addActionListener(listener);

grayButton = new JRadioButton("gray");
grayButton.addActionListener(listener);

fuchsiaButton = new JRadioButton("fuchsia");
fuchsiaButton.addActionListener(listener);

blackButton = new JRadioButton("black");
blackButton.addActionListener(listener);

limeButton = new JRadioButton("lime");
limeButton.addActionListener(listener);

silverButton = new JRadioButton("silver");
silverButton.addActionListener(listener);

maroonButton = new JRadioButton("maroon");
maroonButton.addActionListener(listener);

navyButton = new JRadioButton("navy");
navyButton.addActionListener(listener);

oliveButton = new JRadioButton("olive");
oliveButton.addActionListener(listener);

purpleButton = new JRadioButton("purple");
purpleButton.addActionListener(listener);

tealButton = new JRadioButton("teal");
tealButton.addActionListener(listener);

yellowButton = new JRadioButton("yellow");
yellowButton.addActionListener(listener);

cyanButton = new JRadioButton("cyan");
cyanButton.addActionListener(listener);

orangeButton = new JRadioButton("orange");
orangeButton.addActionListener(listener);

tanButton = new JRadioButton("tan");
tanButton.addActionListener(listener);

lavanderButton = new JRadioButton("lavander");
lavanderButton.addActionListener(listener);

plumButton = new JRadioButton("plum");
plumButton.addActionListener(listener);

blueButton = new JRadioButton("Blue");
blueButton.addActionListener(listener);
blueButton.setSelected(true);
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);

ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(redButton);
group.add(greenButton);
group.add(blueButton);
group.add(plumButton);
group.add(aquaButton);
group.add(grayButton);
group.add(fuchsiaButton);
group.add(blackButton);
group.add(limeButton);
group.add(silverButton);
group.add(maroonButton);
group.add(navyButton);
group.add(oliveButton);
group.add(purpleButton);
group.add(tealButton);
group.add(yellowButton);
group.add(cyanButton);
group.add(orangeButton);
group.add(tanButton);
group.add(lavanderButton);


JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(redButton);
panel.add(greenButton);
panel.add(blueButton);
panel.add(aquaButton);
panel.add(grayButton);
panel.add(fuchsiaButton);
panel.add(blackButton);
panel.add(limeButton);
panel.add(silverButton);
panel.add(maroonButton);
panel.add(navyButton);
panel.add(oliveButton);
panel.add(purpleButton);
panel.add(tealButton);
panel.add(yellowButton);
panel.add(cyanButton);
panel.add(orangeButton);
panel.add(tanButton);
panel.add(lavanderButton);
panel.add(plumButton);

panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,200));
return panel;
}
public void setColor()
{
if(redButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
}
if(greenButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}
if(blueButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
}
  if(aquaButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}
    if(grayButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
}
      if(fuchsiaButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);
}
        if(blackButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}
          if(limeButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
}
            if(silverButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
}
              if(maroonButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
}
                if(navyButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
}
       if(oliveButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
}
        if(purpleButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
}
          if(tealButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
}
            if(yellowButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
}
          if(cyanButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
}
           if(orangeButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
}
             if(tanButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.darkGray);
}
            if(lavanderButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
}
              if(plumButton.isSelected())
{
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
}
}
}
```

Comment: You can use Map.keySet to return a Set of the keys, you can then iterate this Set in a for-loop, extracting the value from the Map with the current key. You would then build a new JRadioButton based on these values. If you need to access the JRadioButton you could put them in an array or List. As for the colors, try looking up web colors in the internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think you are misinterpreting your teacher's instructions. I think when he says "Store up to 20 pairs" it means that your program should be flexible enough to accept up to 20 pairs, not exactly 20 pairs. And this implies that the program does not know the colors in advance. Also, when he says "unique", I believe he means you have to use Java collections to make sure that the colors and their values are unique.

And he most certainly did not intend that you will just fill up a collection without using it. The idea is to use the collection to build the GUI.

Be that as it may, creating a separate variable for each color button and going through a list of if statement is not good programming practice. Whenever you encounter a large group of similar items, on which you have to perform similar actions, it should be your cue to use a collection/array and a loop rather than write the same code over and over. Especially if you don't know if you need to use 10 colors or 20.

So:

1. Decide on a way to input the colors into the program - from command line, from a file, or whatever.
2. Decide on collections that will help you keep both the color name and the color value unique.
3. Write a loop that reads the input, checking for uniqueness, and stopping at 20 or when the data is done.
4. When you have the colors in the collections, use iteration to create buttons and add them to the button group and panel.

Even if you decide that you don't want to work hard on doing input, at the very least put the colors in a static array where you can quickly change it, add and remove colors, and make sure you read from that array into your collections using a loop and not one by one - just as if you were getting it from some kind of input source.

The important part is to have only one place where you change the data. In the way you implemented this, if you now decide to use maroon instead of teal, you have to go through many parts of the code, look for the teal, delete it and use maroon instead.

Now, about your `ActionListener`. Again, if you get to write dozens of similar if statements, you are on the wrong path. But here, what you are missing is the fact that you have a reference to the actual selected button within the `ActionEvent` that is passed to `actionPerformed`.  You can use this reference to know which color to use. For example, when you create the button, if you set the name of the button to be the color, you can use

```
Object eventSource = event.getSource();
String colorName;
if ( eventSource instanceof JRadioButton ) {
    colorName = ((JRadioButton)eventSource).getName();
    // Now get the color value from the collection, build a Color and change the background.
}
```

There are other options like using a `Map<JRadioButton,Color>`. When you create the radio buttons, also create the associated `Color` and put the pair in this map. Now in `actionPerformed` you can simply look up the eventSource you got in this map, and you immediately get the `Color` object.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This project is coming together the way I saw it to start with. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick. You can iterate around the entries in a hashmap and once you know that the repartition disappears

```
public final class FinalProject extends JFrame {

    private Map<String, Color> colors = new TreeMap<String, Color>();

    public FinalProject() {
        colors.put("aqua", Color.decode("#00ffff"));
        colors.put("green", Color.decode("#008000"));
        colors.put("gray", Color.decode("#808080"));
        colors.put("fuchsia", Color.decode("#ff00ff"));
        colors.put("blue", Color.decode("#0000ff"));
        colors.put("black", Color.decode("#000000"));
        colors.put("lime", Color.decode("#00ff00"));
        colors.put("silver", Color.decode("#c0c0c0"));
        colors.put("maroon", Color.decode("#800000"));
        colors.put("olive", Color.decode("#000080"));
        colors.put("red", Color.decode("#ff0000"));
        colors.put("purple", Color.decode("#800080"));
        colors.put("teal", Color.decode("#008080"));
        colors.put("yellow", Color.decode("#ffff00"));
        colors.put("cyan", Color.decode("#00ffff"));
        colors.put("orange", Color.decode("#ffa500"));
        colors.put("tan", Color.decode("#d2b4bc"));
        colors.put("lavender", Color.decode("#e6e6fa"));
        colors.put("plum", Color.decode("#dda0dd"));

        final JPanel colorSwash = new JPanel();
        colorSwash.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

        JPanel colorRadio = new JPanel();
        colorRadio.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 10, 20, 20));

        for(final Map.Entry<String, Color> entry : colors.entrySet()){
            JRadioButton rb = new JRadioButton(entry.getKey());
            rb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    colorSwash.setBackground(entry.getValue());
                }
            });
            colorRadio.add(rb);
        }

        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, colorRadio);
        this.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, colorSwash);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FinalProject fp = new FinalProject();
        fp.pack();
        fp.setVisible(true);
        fp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this small class right before the end of your class:

```
protected static class TreeMapBuilder {
  private TreeMap<String,String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
  public TreeMapBuilder put(String color, String colorName) {
    treeMap.put(color, colorName);
    return this;
  }
  public TreeMap<String, String> end() {
    return treeMap;
  }
}
```

It will allow you to create the TreeMap this way:

```
  TreeMap<String,String> colorselect = new TreeMapBuilder()
     .put("00FFFF","Aqua")
     .put("008000","green")
     .put("808080", "grey")
     .put(.............) (all your colors)
     .end();
```

and can get you some extra points for style :)